# H2O Deep Learning R

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

H2O Deep Learning is running regression by default even though I have ensured that the target variable is a factor (with only two levels). Any leads on how to resolve this ?

Below is the code :

```
dnn_mod <- 
  h2o.deeplearning(x = 2:321,  # column numbers for predictors
                   y = 322,   # column number for label
                   training_frame = sdcs_data, # data in H2O format
                   activation = "TanhWithDropout", # or 'Tanh'
                   input_dropout_ratio = 0.2, # % of inputs dropout
                   hidden_dropout_ratios = c(0.3,0.3,0.3), # % for nodes dropout
                   balance_classes = FALSE, 
                   hidden = c(150,150,150),
                   epochs = 500,
                   #standardize = TRUE,
                   epsilon = 1.0e-5,
                   loss = "CrossEntropy",
                   stopping_rounds = 50,
                   stopping_metric = "AUC")
                   #classification = TRUE)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "is running regression"?

Comment: Defaults to running a regression model rather than classification. Parameters like the CrosseEntropy loss don't make sense in which case and throw an error.

Comment: So don't set loss="CrossEntropy"....

Comment: I don't think that is the point. The problem is not the error, its that H2O doesn't run classification.

Comment: Some data and some more code would be nice , aka a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run classification, then your response variable must be encoded as a "factor" (aka "enum") type.  See this [R code example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/booklets/v2_2015/source/DeepLearning_Vignette_code_examples/deeplearning_examplerun.R) from the [H2O Deep Learning booklet](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_DeepLearning_booklet.html).  This is the case for all H2O algorithms.

Comment: Per my question, I have already ensured that the response is encoded as a "factor".

Comment: Are you sure that column 322 is the response column?  Please paste the output of `h2o.describe(sdcs_data[,322])` or `h2o.getTypes(data)[[322]]`.  It should say "enum".

Comment: Additionally, you can explictly set `distribution = "bernoulli"` and if you have mistakenly not converted your response to a factor, then you will see a message that includes the following: `"bernoulli distribution is not allowed for regression."`

Comment: Lastly, if you are seeing the error, `"For CrossEntropy loss, the response must be categorical."`, then that means that you have not converted the response to a factor.